# Libxml2 missing mac os x 10.10

Tags: ruby, libxml2

```
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.28 (from /Users/Kartik/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.4.1/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/libxslt/1.1.28)...
checking for main() in -llzma... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
```

> libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.

```
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Comment: So what does `mkmf.log` say? Software installation problem belongs to http://superuser.com though.

Comment: also on OS X 10.11

Answer (score 85):

i fiddled around with this for quite a while and the following worked for me..

1) install libxml2 with homebrew

```
brew install libxml2
```

2) install the gem via

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install nokogiri:1.6.4.1 -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me: 
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install nokogiri

Comment: +1. I spent an hour having fun with wonderful nokogiri. But the solution was so simple! A 255 character line of super specific commands. Makes complete sense.

Comment: I am getting the error "libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!" although the libxml in /usr/local/Cellar/... is 2.9.2. Strange.

Comment: This is perfect.  Sudo can be omitted if you are using rvm or rbenv.

Comment: @user152468, I am also getting "libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required". Brew installs libxml2-2.9.2 so not sure if that 2- is involved somehow?

Comment: Thank you. Works on OS X 10.11 too.

Comment: @user152468 I ran: `sudo gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2`. I had to install the newest version of ruby though.

Answer (score 15):

For any who are still getting "libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!" message, removing --use-system-libraries from hlv's step 2 above, worked for me.

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install nokogiri:1.6.4.1 -- --with-xml=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally ended up with this version independent line:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install nokogiri  -n /usr/local/bin -- --with-xml=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (assuming Xcode is installed):

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.‌platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 --use-system-libraries
```

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/28767045/1884907 (credits to lx00st)

Comment: It should be "nokogiri" instead of "nkogiri". Thanks.

Comment: Or use `/usr/include/libxml2` instead of the long `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.‌platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/libxml2`.

Comment: As of today, this worked:
`gem install libxml-ruby -v '3.0.0' -- --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 --use-system-libraries`

Answer (score 3):

(For MacOX 10.12.x) Perhaps you want to `brew install libxml2` and also try linking into `/usr/local/` first: `brew link --force libxml2`, then try that `gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries`.

Answer (score 1):

Using ports:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml=/opt/local/lib/libxml2.a
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution, using ports:

`sudo ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries`

By default, it will compile for x86_64 and i386, architecture for i386 should disabled, because the dependencies libraries in port only provide x86_64 version by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a rehash of all the other answers, but this worked for me:

```
 gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2' -- --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.16 --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libxml2  --use-system-libraries
```