# Problems with libxml2 when installing Ruby on Rails on OSX Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-mavericks, libxml2

I'm having a problem installing Ruby on Rails in my terminal.

Has anyone else encountered the following error in the terminal:

```
checking for main() in -llzma... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I'm using the standard bash:

```
$ gem install rails
```

How would I go about fixing this? I've tried a few things here on stack exchange but nothing so far has worked...

Using `$ brew list` in the terminal yields:

```
Michaels-iMac:~ iMacHome$ brew list
autoconf    libksba     libxslt     pkg-config
automake    libtool     libyaml     readline
libgpg-error    libxml2     openssl
Michaels-iMac:~ iMacHome$
```

It seems to be there...

Comment: Try to install `libxml2` use Homebrew.

Comment: I've done that. Still has problems.

Comment: Are you using system ruby or RVM, rbenv ruby manager?

Comment: Can you show the libs installed with ***brew installed*** ? Could cross-check and see what's missing. As it works for me and I do not have libxml installed.

Comment: @maxd I'm using RVM....I think.

Comment: How do I repair my build toolchain in the terminal...?

Comment: Which version of ruby is selected in rvm by default (`rvm list`)?

Comment: Michael, open Xcode and check if the commandline tools are properly installed and up to date as well.

Comment: @maxd =* ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]

Comment: @NekoNova I used xcode-select --install but how can I check?

Comment: Depends on your version but if you did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools then that rules out the commandline issue. Could still be a missing lib on your system...

Comment: So how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: run **brew installed** and update your answer with the output, so we can see if a lib is missing. You could also check if the libxml2 library exists in /opt/local/ somewhere and link to it manually.

Comment: @NekoNova I've tried brew installed and I get: Error: Unknown command: installed

Comment: Ahh brew list did the trick. See an edited version of the question for the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you have Xcode installed try this

```bash
gem install rails -- --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.‌platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 --use-system-libraries
```

Comment: he's using RVM, it's better to use the package system of RVM to get the libxml2 library, as that is known to work properly inside the RVM installation.

Comment: This worked, it might be a rvm workaround but it seemed to work.

Comment: you should try  NekoNova's answer as well because its not "rvm way" and you will have to run this wired params with all new gemsets

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be your RVM.

Try either this command:

```
 rvm cleanup all
 rvm pkg uninstall libxml2
 rvm reinstall all --force
```

or upgrade/reinstall to the latest RVM installation.

--
To properly install the rails gem globally for a Ruby version:

```
rvm use <rubyversion>
gem install rails
```

example to use rails on ruby 2.1.5:

```
rvm use 2.1.5
gem install rails
```

Comment: Side question: should I be using "$ dvm gem install rails"...?

Comment: `rvm pkg` is now deprecated in favor of `rvm autolibs`.