# Install bosh_cli with gem on mac os 10.10

Tags: ruby, macos, cloud-foundry

Im am trying to install cloud-foundry, and therefore bosh_lite on my OSX 10.10.

while doing gem install bosh_cli, I get:  libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.

So I did brew install libxml2 and followed the instructions here:

[Libxml2 missing mac os x 10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878263/libxml2-missing-mac-os-x-10-10)

But I am getting the error "libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!" although the libxml in /usr/local/Cellar/... is 2.9.2.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had overlooked an error at the beginning:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

The following post solved my issue: 
[Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

I had to do:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install bosh_cli
```