# Error when installing rails, failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following [this Go Rails tutorial](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.12-sierra) and I'm running into trouble when I reach the step to install rails. I'm calling

```
sudo gem install rails -v 5.0.1
```

in the terminal and getting this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/ext/nokogiri
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170302-50105-1af2foa.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/gem_make.out
```

I'm not really sure what to make of this. I've tried reinstalling uninstalling and reinstalling zlib but it didn't seem to change anything. I'm on OS X Sierra version 10.12.3 by the way.

Comment: You need to install libxml2 library. Have you tried it?

Comment: I just tried brew install libxml2 and I got "Warning: libxml2 is a keg-only and another version is linked to opt.
Use `brew install --force` if you want to install this version". Then I tried sudo gem install rails -v 5.0.1 and got the same original error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115403/error-gem-install-rails-libxml2-is-missing) using

```
sudo gem install rails -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/
```