# Failed to build gem native extension.(extconf failed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I am getting runtime error on generating executable file while rails installation.

```
gem install rails -- --use-system-libraries
```

I have checked similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115403/error-gem-install-rails-libxml2-is-missing) here, but in my case there seems no library missing. It says "You have to install development tools first" but does not specifies which tool.
Error log can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/SNKsPDma).
I am on archlinux (4.12.4-1-ARCH).

Comment: I've started with a completely fresh `archlinux/base` Docker image, and I'll document the steps to get all of the Rails dependencies built. 

Generally speaking in these circumstances the 'development tools' refer to `gcc` and `make`, then you'll get a message for each missing library and you can just install them one by one. 

Anyway, I have it working now, I'll write up the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To discover the minimum set of tools and libraries you'll need, I started with a completely fresh `archlinux/base` image in Docker as follows:

```
docker run -it archlinux/base
```

...and now inside the container...

First of all I changed out the default mirrorlist as the mirror in the image didn't seem to work. If your `pacman` is working fine you don't need to do this.

```
rm /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
echo "Server = http://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/\$repo/os/\$arch" > /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
pacman-db-upgrade
pacman -Syyu --noconfirm
```

Next, I installed ruby and the C++ tools.

```
pacman -S ruby gcc make --noconfirm
```

Attempting to run `gem install rails -- --use-system-libraries` led to the expected complaints about missing libraries for Nokogiri. It depends on `libxml2` and `libxslt`, so...

```
pacman -S libxml2 libxslt --noconfirm
```

Finally you can run `gem install rails -- --use-system-libraries` and it will finish successfully.

If you want to install rails without `--use-system-libraries` (which is **probably what you want**, as Nokogiri laments about not being 100% compatible with OS-bundled versions of `libxml2`) just install `git` and `awk` through pacman instead of installing the xml libraries, e.g.

```
pacman -S ruby gcc make git awk --noconfirm
gem install rails
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, I am able to install with git and awk without using system-libraries. Can you help me understand how awk and git helped with the problem ?

Comment: I am still not able to find rails using "rails --version". It installed correctly log https://pastebin.com/Mdqc7YWv

Comment: Awk and git were used in the Nokogiri build process. I'm not sure exactly what it used them for--awk will probably have been used for simple command line text processing, git will have been used to pull down extra code from somewhere.

Comment: As for finding your rails command, you'll most likely need to add gems to your path. I'm not sure of the specifics of doing that in Arch Linux though.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ruby Look at rubygems setup here, specifically with regards to the path setup.