# libxml-ruby: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: macos, rubygems, homebrew, libxml2, libxml-ruby

I'm trying to install `libxml-ruby`.
I have installed `libxml2`, `libxslt` and `coreutils`

I have also read other posts regarding the issue but none solved it for me.

`brew list libxslt`

```
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28_1/bin/xslt-config
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28_1/bin/xsltproc
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28_1/include/libexslt/ (3 files)
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28_1/include/libxslt/ (21 files)
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28_1/lib/libexslt.0.dylib
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28_1/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28_1/lib/pkgconfig/ (2 files)
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28_1/lib/ (5 other files)
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28_1/share/aclocal/libxslt.m4
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28_1/share/doc/ (90 files)
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28_1/share/man/ (3 files)
```

`brew list libxml2`

```
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/bin/xml2-config
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/bin/xmlcatalog
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/bin/xmllint
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/include/libxml2/ (47 files)
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/lib/cmake/libxml2/libxml2-config.cmake
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/lib/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/lib/ (3 other files)
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/share/aclocal/libxml.m4
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/share/doc/ (153 files)
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/share/gtk-doc/ (55 files)
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/share/man/ (4 files)
```

`gem install libxml-ruby` produces the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing libxml-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /opt/rubies/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libxml-ruby-2.9.0/ext/libxml
/opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160630-68248-1qaz7dk.rb extconf.rb
checking for libxml/xmlversion.h in /opt/include/libxml2,/opt/local/include/libxml2,/usr/local/include/libxml2,/usr/include/libxml2... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-xml2-config
    --without-xml2-config
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
 extconf failure: need libxml2.

    Install the library or try one of the following options to extconf.rb:

      --with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config
      --with-xml2-dir=/path/to/libxml2
      --with-xml2-lib=/path/to/libxml2/lib
      --with-xml2-include=/path/to/libxml2/include


To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.3.0-static/libxml-ruby-2.9.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libxml-ruby-2.9.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.3.0-static/libxml-ruby-2.9.0/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Did you confirm that `libxml/xmlversion.h` is in one of the four directories that it claimed it's checking `/opt/include/libxml2,/opt/local/include/libxml2,/usr/local/include/libxml2,/usr/include/libxml2`?

Comment: I solved this by running

`gem install libxml-ruby -v '3.0.0' -- --with-xml2-config=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin/xml2-config --with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include`

Comment: Example which works for me (Please verify your libxml2 path)

`gem install libxml-ruby -v '3.0.0' -- --with-xml2-config=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2/bin/xml2-config --with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2/ --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2/lib/ --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2/include/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The high level issue is shown here:

```
checking for libxml/xmlversion.h in /opt/include/libxml2,/opt/local/include/libxml2,/usr/local/include/libxml2,/usr/include/libxml2... no
```

Basically, the installer is telling you it can't find `libxml/xmlversion.h` but more generally it most likely can't find your `libxml2` location. It tells you which four directories it's looking in so the first step is to check those directories to see if `libxml2` is there.

Assuming it's not in any of those four locations, you need to find it. Run `find / -name xmlversion.h` (might need `sudo`) to figure out where `libxml2` got installed. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27086549/1241782) I'm guessing your issue is that `brew` installed it to `/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2` but you should confirm that. Once you have the location you can manually point your `gem install` command to it. Something like this: (but fill in `path/to` with your actual path)

```
gem install libxml-ruby --with-xml2-dir=/path/to/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/path/to/libxml2/lib --with-xml2-include=/path/to/libxml2/include
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the options to install the gem and it worked. But I need these options in the bundle config. I have tried the following config but it didnt work:
`BUNDLE_BUILD__LIBXML-RUBY: "--with-xml2-lib=/opt/boxen/homebrew/opt/libxml2/lib --with-xml2-include=/opt/boxen/homebrew/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2
  --with-xslt-lib=/opt/boxen/homebrew/opt/libxslt/lib --with-xslt-include=/opt/boxen/homebrew/opt/libxslt/include"`

Comment: @CarlMarkham I would recommend posting the bundle config issue as a separate question so you can past the full command terminal and output.

Comment: Building on this answer. The following worked for me. Use "find" to locate your xmlversion.h file --> gem install libxml-ruby -- --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/ --use-system-libraries

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar issue after I had used brew to install libxml2

Brew link solved the issue `brew link --force libxml2`

Comment: But you are aware that libxml2 is always part of macOS and now you just added a 2nd copy of it with brew in a 2nd location that could possibly be incompatible with the already installed one, are you?

Answer (score 16):

Life after upgrading to macOS Mojave.

```
xcode-select --install
brew install libxml2
brew link --force libxml2
gem install libxml-ruby -v '2.9.0' -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include="$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)"/usr/include/libxml2
```

In my example I installed version `2.9.0` of the libxml-ruby gem. Change the version string to suit your needs. If available, examine the `Gemfile.lock` to identify which version of `libxml-ruby` Bundler is needs to install.

Comment: Without specifying an arbitrary version, I succeeded with just
`sudo gem update libxml-ruby -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include="$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)"/usr/include/libxml2`

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you. The `brew link --force` gave me a warning that it refused to link it, but somehow I guess that didn't matter

Comment: That's creating a _really_ confusing situation.  You're linking homebrew's libxml2 (breaking it out of its keg-only status) *and* explicitly listing OSX's include folder.  What does the gem use now use as xml2's *lib* folder?

Comment: This worked for me without the dreaded:
`brew link --force libxml2`

Answer (score 13):

Homebrew:

> libxml2 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
>   because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
>   parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

So, we need to set libxml path directly

```
brew install libxml2

gem install libxml-ruby \
-- \
--with-xml2-config="$(brew --prefix libxml2)/bin/xml2-config"
```

P.S.

If you get the exception on lastest rubies:

Just ignore it.  The gem was successfully installed. Just the Rdoc documentation generation failed.

```
The internal error was:

        (NoMethodError) undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Works on Mojave!

Comment: Alternatively, avoid the rdoc error by not generating documentation: `$ gem install --no-document libxml-ruby -- --with-xml2-config=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin/xml2-config`

Answer (score 7):

macOS comes with `libmxl2` installed, always, there is no need to use a utility like `brew` to install it first. Yet the headers are not found in `/usr/include/libxml` but in `/usr/include/libxml2/libxml`.

The configure script of the `libxml-ruby` `gem` tries to detect if `libxml` is installed by compiling code that looks like this:

`#include <libxml/xmlversion.h>`

But when compiling with the compiler shipped with Xcode, only this code would work:

`#include <libxml2/libxml/xmlversion.h>`

The trick is to let the configure script know where to find the headers. On a macOS system with Xcode installed, the following will work:

```
gem install libxml-ruby -v '3.1.0' -- --with-xml2-include=`xcrun --show-sdk-path`/usr/include/libxml2
```

Answer (score 4):

I also used `brew` to install `libxml2` but needed the following options:

```
brew install libxml2 --with-xml2-config
gem install libxml-ruby -- --with-xml2-config=/usr/local/homebrew/opt/libxml2/bin/xml2-config
```

Comment: Worked for me. `--with-xml2-config` is not needed (anymore?) for the brew installation.

Comment: But you are aware that libxml2 is always part of macOS and now you just added a 2nd copy of it with brew in a 2nd location that could possibly be incompatible with the already installed one, are you?

Comment: This solution is definitely for an older setup. As Frizlab mentions, `--with-xml2-config` is no longer a valid option. On a newer setup, I used this [linked SO thread to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222641/bundle-install-fails-to-install-libxml-ruby). Mecki's comment seems valid but I haven't tested.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to:

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/ $ 
open macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

To force the reinstallation of the headers for macOS 10.14.