# AWS EB libxml2 and libxslt error

Tags: python, macos, amazon-ec2, libxml2, libxslt

As some background, I am running macOS, and am deploying Python apps to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EB).

My app does not require `libxml2-devel` or `libxslt-devel` to run on locally, but when pushed to Amazon EC2, both `libxml2-devel` and `libxslt-devel` for some reason become dependencies.  Via SSH, I can install both  using `sudo yum install -y libxml2-devel libxslt-devel`.  Is this an issue I can correct, or is this a problem with AWS EB?

Also, I have tired uninstall-then-installing both `libxslt` and `libxml2` in order to get the libxml2 Python bindings, and that did not solve the problem.

```sh
brew uninstall libxslt
brew uninstall libxml2
brew install libxml2 --with-python
brew link --force libxml2
brew install libxslt
brew link --force libxslt
```

Below is the error message from the AWS health console:

```
Application update failed at 2017-02-21T08:15:39Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed.

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): appdirs==1.4.0 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django==1.9.2 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
Collecting lxml==3.7.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 3))
Using cached lxml-3.7.2.tar.gz
Collecting packaging==16.8 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 4))
Using cached packaging-16.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing==2.1.10 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 5))
Using cached pyparsing-2.1.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests==2.13.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 6))
Using cached requests-2.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six==1.10.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 7))
Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: lxml, six, pyparsing, packaging, requests
Running setup.py install for lxml
Complete output from command /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-DmDEWN/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Wqejfh-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/python/run/venv/include/site/python2.7/lxml:
Building lxml version 3.7.2.
Building without Cython.
ERROR: /bin/sh: xslt-config: command not found

** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:515:
src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:14:31: error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:16:4: error: #error the development package of libxml2 (header files etc.) is not installed correctly
src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:23:32: error: libxslt/xsltconfig.h: No such file or directory
src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:25:4: error: #error the development package of libxslt (header files etc.) is not installed correctly
src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:186:25: error: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory
In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:515:
src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:188: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘xmlBuf’
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878263/libxml2-missing-mac-os-x-10-10

Comment: The Amazon Linux AMI doesn't provide an lxml RPM package, so EB tries to install lxml with pip or easy_install which compiles it from source. Either add the libxml2 development packages to your config, or try to install the lxml RPM from another source.